# VNC through server to pc behind firewall not in the same LAN

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, vnc, remote-control

I have a PC in my home network that I need to be able to access remotely world wide via VNC (or some other equivalent protocol, it really doesn't matter). It doesn't allow for any direct incoming connections due to security reasons and also doesn't have a static IP.
I also have a server that is accessible via SSH with a static IP and no firewall. It is NOT in the same LAN as the home PC.

Now, is there a way for me to connect my home PC to the intermediary server so that I can control it by logging into that server with a third device?

All solutions I've found for VNC tunneling thus far only seem to work when server and tunnel share the same LAN so that a direct connection can be established from the intermediary server to the VNC device. That's not what I want - I want to establish a permanent (or auto-reconnecting) connection between the VNC server and the intermediary server.

All devices are running Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've found a solution (albeit a bit primitive) myself. I wrote a simple script that makes the machine that I want to access execute

```
x11vnc -connect_or_exit <intermediary server IP>
```

every 30 seconds. This will of course fail as long as there is no VNC viewer running on the server. So it'll fail and the machine tries again.

When I want to actually access the machine, I connect to the intermediary server via SSH with X11 forwarding enabled. Now, I launch vinagre with enabled reverse connections on that intermediary server. After that the machine running x11vnc can actually connect to the server and a reverse VNC connection is established, the resulting window of which is shown to me via X11 forwarding.

This is certainly not the most elegant solution. It means that the images coming from the controlled machine are compressed via vnc to get to the intermediary server, then decompressed, then compressed for X11 forwarding again. This is not a very good solution in terms of performance, though the reaction speed for simple desktop applications is still usable for my purposes. Feel free to still answer if you know a better alternative!